# Achieve different text sizes of RadioButton programmatically

Tags: android

I'm using different sizes of text for different screen resolutions. To do this, I created a resource `values/dimens.xml` and `values-sw720dp/dimens.xml`. But I do not understand how to use the values from `dimens.xml` when creating `RadioButton` programmatically?

```java
RadioButton newRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);

newRadioButton.setTextSize(30); //how to use the values from  dimens.xml?
newRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#002060"));

radiogroup.addView(newRadioButton, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.test)
```

Comment: It was seen a feature, on the phone with a resolution of 540x960 size of text `RadioButton` taken from the `values / dimens.xml` and on the phone with a resolution of 720x1280 from the `values-sw720dp / dimens.xml`. But for the rest of items that are not programmatically, as defined in the layout Xml text size is taken correctly. Why is this happening?